# Server push using Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, server-push

I want to create a connection between a client and the server with Grails so that the server pushes messages to the client.

I tried the [events-push-plugin](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/blob/master/README.md), but I did not manage to solve my problem using the it.

Comment: Your English is not bad, but we need your code to help you find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

That plugin is unfortunately not well-maintained. Check out [spring-websocket](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket) which is.

Answer (score 4):

Use http://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket plugin (should be using grails 2.4.4 and above)

In your service class, 
inject the service brokerMessagingTemplate and in your service method push a msg to client by

```
brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend "/topic/hello", "hello from service!"
```

In gsp file,you need to subscribe to the topic '/topic/hello', below is the sample code.

```
<asset:javascript src="spring-websocket" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 

    var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
    var client = Stomp.over(socket);

    client.connect({}, function() {
    client.subscribe("/topic/hello", function(message) {
    $("#helloDiv").append(message.body);
    });
    });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can we define idle timeout in this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with [vert.x](http://vertx.io) recently. It's not a grails plugin, but is really simple to use.